# Web API 2 project with numerous controllers?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, projects-and-solutions

From a maintenance and deployment standpoint, does it make sense to have one Web API 2 project with many (30+) controllers, or 30+ micro Web API 2 project with one controller each?

I started down the path of having them all in a single project whose structure would look like this:

**Comapany.Project.Api (solution)**

- AccountController
- OrderController
- InventoryController
- //many more here
- AddressController

I've come to think this will be problematic when deploying since we just use a file system publish that deletes all files prior to publish. If I make a change to the orderController and have to deploy during the day to production, I will bring down many other services.

I'm about to rework my project structure to something like this:

**Company.Project (solution)**

- Company.Project.AccountApi
- Comapny.Project.OrderApi
- Company.Project.InventoryApi
- //many more here
- Company.Project.AddressApi

Then I would have a

- Company.Project.Core

This core project would contain some shared code like extension methods, custom exceptions, actionFilters, etc.

I know the answer to this could be very subjective. However, I'm looking for concrete reasons to choose one solution structure over the other. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I stick with all controllers in one project. I also tend to like to use a single Web API controller per domain / tier / whatever you do to logically break down your application into more manageable pieces so that the amount of controllers can be mitigated.

I've documented my practices on my [GitHub Wiki](https://github.com/JaimeStill/Reference/wiki/ASP.NET-WebAPI-Attribute-Routing).